# Laravel 4: get url parameter from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel 4 and I'm currently having the following problem:
In my routes.php I have the line:

```
Route::get('maps/{map_type}', 'MapsController@loadMaps');
```

And in my MapsController I'd like to get the {map_type} to use it.

So my question: How can I retrieve map_type in my Controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first argument in your `loadMaps` method is your map type.

```
public function loadMaps($map_type) {
    return $map_type;
}
```

Take a look at the first two code snippets on http://laravel.com/docs/controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers receive parameters as parameters in the called function:

```
class MapsController extends BaseController {
    public function loadMaps($map_type) {}
}
```

Check http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#basic-controllers for more info